# Error installing htk-tool

Tags: software-installation

When I try to compile and install HTK, it produces the following error:

```
HTK is now ready to be built.

Type "make all" to build the HTK libraries
and tools.

Then "make install" to install them.

The tools will be installed in /usr/local/bin

Build notes: Language Modelling tools will be
built. HDecode will not be built. You can build
it manually later by running 'make hdecode
install-hdecode'

**************************************************
user@EESBLRP105:~/htk$  make all

(cd HTKLib && make HTKLib.a) \
      || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/htk/HTKLib'
gcc  -m32 -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="x86_64"' -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2 -I. -DPHNALG   -c -o HGraf.o HGraf.c
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:27:0,
                 from HShell.h:40,
                 from HGraf.c:54:
/usr/include/features.h:374:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <sys/cdefs.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [HGraf.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/htk/HTKLib'
make: *** [HTKLib/HTKLib.a] Error 1
```

Comment: HTK-3.4.1 : The time stamp is 2009, long before the new Debian path´s were introduced. Solution for "sys/cdefs.h" : `./configure CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several pitfalls when building HTK with e.g. Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64. a) The new path´s. b) HTK is built with gcc -m32 : i386 build prerequisites are required.
Much easier if CentOS 6.9 - i386 or CentOS 7 - x86_64.

The package `htk-tools_3.4.1-ubuntu14_i386.deb` was created on Ubuntu 14.04 - i386, the files are from a HTK-3.4.1 build with CentOS 7.

Link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Di29AvqoRBEJ4haW2nusPT1wMPkE14B1/view?usp=sharing → Provides /usr/local/bin/{ 37 tools }.

Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64 : Download, and install :

```
cd Downloads/
sudo gdebi htk-tools_3.4.1-ubuntu14_i386.deb
            // some 32bits dependencies will be installed too
```