# HTK Installation problem

Tags: software-installation, xorg, shared-library

I’m trying to install HTK tools. I have this message when I type `make all`:

```
error : "/usr/bin/ld : cannot find -lX11"
```

Comment: Did you install the `libx11-dev` package?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: David Foerster : `./configure` is not checking for libX11, the errors will happen when 'make' is run : `error : "/usr/bin/ld : cannot find -lX11"` ... I.e. when the 32bits `libx11-dev` is missing.

Comment: Finally, HTk works with 32 bits architecture , i solved the problem by migrating to 32bits ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

HTK is built with gcc -m32, which means i386 build prerequisites are required : `libx11-dev:i386` . And : HTK-3.4.1 → The time stamp is 2009, long before the new Debian path´s were introduced. Please do  : `./configure CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`

You can also install the binary HTK-tools package `htk-tools_3.4.1-ubuntu14_i386.deb` : See [Error installing htk-tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010581/error-installing-htk-tool/1010704#1010704)

Comment: Another old fart who knows [the things kids don't know any more](https://askubuntu.com/a/1024824/344926) (both answers upvotes although it's against corporate policy to duplicate answers instead of closing as a duplicate...