# Does Ubuntu swap even when there is no swap configured?

Tags: swap

In my `/etc/fstab` there is no `swap` partition.

`top` displays `KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used`

and `swapon` shows nothing.

So it looks like swap is disabled. But when the system runs out of physical memory, it starts behaving like it's swapping: the system becomes nearly unresponsive, disc access indicator is on all the time; if I manage to close a heavy process (or if it gets killed, probably by an Out-of-Memory killer), the system becomes responsive again.

Does Ubuntu still swap in such a case?

The system is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What does `swapon` show? No output means no swap is configured.

Comment: "like it's swapping: the system becomes nearly unresponsive" sorry how is that "like swapping". That's your system running with not enough memory to do what needs to be done. "Swap" would mean it drops memory into swap where it decides it has not been used for a while and it is deemed more efficient to clear some memory for new tasks.

Comment: +1, the system runs out of RAM.

Comment: @PerlDuck `swapon` shows nothing

Comment: @mikewhatever I'm probably misunderstanding something. When a system runs out of RAM, shouldn't it result in OOM killer killing a process, or some process crashing due to an unsuccessful attempt to allocate memory? Both of these would bring relief, but this does not happen every time. I do have some JVMs that may put all their CPU resources in garbage collection, but it should not freeze the system, I guess. Once again, I am probably misunderstanding something; could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your question was about Swap, and it was answered. Questions about running out of memory don't belong in this question. This is a Question & Answer site, not a conversation forum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The short answer:

If there is no swap, Ubuntu will not swap.

#### The long answer:

What  happens is that the Linux kernel memory manager (not really Ubuntu itself) will first try to consolidate memory into chunks it can allocate to the applications requesting said memory (the slowdown you're seeing) and if it cannot, these applications will crash, thus freeing up their memory for the more well-behaved applications that did not crash.

The Kernel's OOM Killer[¹](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153586/90054) is only invoked if and only if there is no other way of doing so[²](https://lwn.net/Articles/668126/#reaper/) and looking at your high disk usage, you're running into the [too small to fail memory allocation rule](https://lwn.net/Articles/627419/).  The relevant section states:

> In other words, the allocating process cannot proceed because it is waiting for its allocation call to return. That call cannot return until memory is freed, which requires the victim process to exit. The OOM killer will also wait for the victim to exit before (possibly) choosing a second process to kill.

#### The rant:

Back when I was a kid <s>and the **only** qualification you needed to start in the IT industry was the ability to read manuals</s> and 32K was the norm and 64K was "wow", we used to check every memory allocation and display "Out of memory" when we couldn't allocate memory at an application level, which today's <s>kids</s> programmers don't do any more as <s>they're spoilt rotten with multiple monitors, huge SSDs and systems that are generally better than the systems their software actually runs on</s> they are not used to having systems run out of memory any more...

## ;-)

Comment: +1 for the details in the long answer and the rant :-)

Comment: Thank you for the point about memory compaction. The ever-shining disk access LED still remains a mystery for me, but I guess I have to create another question about it :)

Comment: Why do you claim OOM Killers don't exist? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory / https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136291/103151 / https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/153585/103151

Comment: **RomanPuchkovskiy** Disk light is *very probably* the invocation of the OOM killer (which doesn't get invoked often, so resides on disk). after reading @ByteCommander 's docs. *Mystery solved!*

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy: I've learned stuff too while answering!  Win-Win situation!

Comment: I came across this question and answer while experiencing the same problem.  What I still don't get is why reading the OOM killer from disk would cause the disk to thrash for 20 minutes or more.